Django static files not working on cpanel
my settings.py static settings are
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/mywebsite/public_html/dj/static/'

I have run: manage.py collectstatic successfully. 
I restarted the app.
But when i hit the URL http://mywebsite/admin there is no CSS.
Maybe there's something to do with .htaccess somewhere.
I need help
P.S. I'm using shared hosting with cPanel and without Terminal access

Please open the console and check the response's status code for static file requests. It helps us where to search for the actual problem from

I don't have terminal access. When I run manage.py collectstatic in cPanel's interface there was no errors.

I solved the problem by creating a directory named static inside public_html and putting all my static files there either manually or using manage collectstatic.
So instead of
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/mywebsite/public_html/dj/static/'``` 
I made 

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/mywebsite/public_html/static/'
In other words the static folder needs to be directly inside public_html and not inside another folder. I don't know wether this is a general rule for cPanel or just happened in my configuration.

